# WPF Datagrid hosted on Winforms does not show checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, datagrid

I have WPF datagrid user control which I have to host it in Winforms. WPF Datagrid control is embedded inside a usercontrol. I have a winforms application which has element host control in it. Child of the element host is the WPF usercontrol (the one which has a datagrid). 
On the wpf datagrid, I have a checkbox for every row (created dynamically when a row is loaded).

When the wpf usercontrol is loaded in winforms, (on the element host) I can get the rows, but not the checkbox. Checkbox visibility is visible and I can see some placeholders in the row.

Is there something I missed? Do I need to declare the checkbox differently on wpf datagrid, so that it is visible on winforms too?

here is the code for checkbox creation

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
col1.Header = "Select Columns";
col1.Width = 30;
FrameworkElementFactory factory1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
Binding b1 = new Binding("IsSelected");
b1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
factory1.SetValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, b1);
factory1.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(chkSelect_Checked));
factory1.AddHandler(CheckBox.UncheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(chkSelect_UnChecked));
DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
cellTemplate1.VisualTree = factory1;
col1.CellTemplate = cellTemplate1;
col1.CellStyle = new Style();
col1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
dgGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
```

Comment: OMG Why are you not using XAML for this?

Comment: TemplateColumn cannot be embedded in winforms...so created a datacheckboxcolumn with  selected binding and added events dynamically